# What material could be used to replicate body fat in an advanced android/ humanoid robot?

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, robots

I think that robots in the future will have to have a system similar to adipose tissue that would have similar functions of those of people and animals. I believe that if an android is supposed to replicate as much as biological functions as possible an artifitial body fat could be important. This would also make the robot look softer and function as some kind of lubrificant or a slime-like battery for special needs.

This is android 19 from DBZ. I like him. He looks quite overweight:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the 3 images add to the question? What does the info that you like that android add to the question? Please, stick to the problem description and to the question.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of properties of fat you are trying to replicate. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

## Silicone.

Silicone is already used by plastic surgeons to replicate human body fat in implants given to humans. It would not be a stretch for future roboticists who seek to create lifelike humanoid robots to include it in the construction of said robots.

Comment: Which properties of fat does silicone replicate?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Im not totally sure, since I’m not a plastic surgeon, but probably the aesthetic qualities of it given that it’s used in things like breast and butt implants.